# Как удалить неиспользуемые стили css?

Tags: css

В chrome нету вкладки "legacy audits".
Для firefox расширения в новой версии уже не поддерживаются
Те сервисы которые нагуглил - почти все не работают.

---

Все,нашел крутой онлайн сервис https://uncss-online.com/

Comment: Сайт не на хостинге,а локально

Answer (score 1):

Это можно проверять только на одной странице, но не факт что удаленные стили не используются на других страницах.